# Get XML Node Text using LINQ To XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Trying to get the value for the "title" node from this XML -> http://feeds.feedburner.com/dotnetshoutout-published

I am using this code:

```
var d = XDocument.Load("http://feeds.feedburner.com/dotnetshoutout-published");
var node = d.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "title").FirstOrDefault();
```

Always returns null. Making me crazy, any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an Xml Namespace on your elements.If so, your element name won't be just `title`, it will be `namespace + title`.Instead you should check the `LocalName` :

```
var node = d.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.LocalName == "title").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, you can look at the namespace of your elements and create an [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it to fetch elements:

```
XNamespace ns = "yournamespace";
var node = d.Root.Descendants(ns + "title").FirstOrDefault();
```

You can read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx) to find more info about how to deal with xml namespaces.

Comment: Since the XML document in this case is an [Atom feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29#Example_of_an_Atom_1.0_feed), the namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`.

Comment: Awesome got it working like this;

    var d = XDocument.Load(url);
    var ns = d.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
    var node = d.Root.Descendants(ns + "title").FirstOrDefault();
            string title = node != null ? node.Value : "";